# How to query data from MYSQLdb with Python2.7 if I want query "date-1"?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, debian, mysql-python

So, I need to query data from MYSQLdb in every day, that's why I prefer to use a query which one I can query the actual date - 1 data. For example if I run my script today at Nov 13, I need the all information from Nov 12 (from the ACTUAL_DATE - on the picture).

I have got a column in the MYSQLdb, which looks like this :

[image]

Is this any query, is this any chance to query data with this "DATE - 1" logic? So I have to analyse the last 6 character in the ACTUAL_DATE columns, because the last 2 show the day, the last 4 show the months (year is not important!)

This MYSQLdb refresh in every day, that's why I need to find a way which one I can query the REAL DATE - 1 day from this table.

I know the code has to looking like this :

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
        user='user1',
        passwd='',
        db='database1',
        use_unicode=True,
        charset="utf8")
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """ select #I NEED SOMETHING HERE.. 
    from OSSZES
    into outfile '/tmp/test.csv'
    fields terminated by ';'
    enclosed by '"'
    lines terminated by '\n';
    """
cursor.execute(query)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

But how can I write this select query if it is exist in mysqldb?

Comment: if you use the DATE or DATETIME datatype instead off using what looks like a VARCHAR datatype. You can use `SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [column] = NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY`

Comment: Yes, but if I am using NOW() it is returnig with the current date and time..and how can i compare with my ACTUAL_DATE?

Comment: ive posted a answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use off the function STR_TO_DATE to format the VARCHAR format into a DATETIME format.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM ( 
  # test data replace this with your table name
  SELECT 
   'Sunday, Nov 12' AS A

  UNION ALL  

  SELECT 
    'Saturday, Nov 11'
)
 AS records 
WHERE 
   MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(A, '%W, %b %d')) = MONTH(NOW())
 AND
   DAY(STR_TO_DATE(A, '%W, %b %d')) = DAY(NOW()) - 1
```

**Result**

```
A               
----------------
Sunday, Nov 12
```

Comment: Is this 3 select query in one? Or how is it looking in python code, can you update your code with my code?

Comment: Replace `( 
  # test data replace this with your table name
  SELECT 
   'Sunday, Nov 12' AS A

  UNION ALL  

  SELECT 
    'Saturday, Nov 11'
)
 AS records ` with your table name.. cant help you with the python code because i can't write python code.

Comment: It isn't a good solution for me, because with this i can analyse only 1 day, but i want to do this without overwrite my code in every day, thats why i try to compare the NOW() with my ACTUAL_DATE columns

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a combination of 'pandas' and 'datetime' modules:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_sql_table('OSSZES',connection)
df['ACTUAL_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ACTUAL_DATE'])
mask = df['ACTUAL_DATE'] < dt.date.today()
df_new = df.loc[mask]
df_new.to_csv('/tmp/test.csv')
```